# Can I apply for another visa while in another country?

Tags: visas, schengen, southeast-europe, balkans

I am a Filipino passport holder and let's just say that I currently have a valid visa (and am living in) an Eastern European country that is not part of the Schengen system. Should I want to visit a Western European country could I apply for a visa at the country where I am currently staying in the Balkans?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can - but [they want to see a justification](http://www.immihelp.com/visas/schengenvisa/application.html) why you're not applying from within your home country.

[image]

The justification can be as simple as "I'm living in this country (please see attached copy of my residence permit)".

Comment: Actually, being a residence of the country where you apply is a requirement for French visa at least. So being a tourist is not enough, even if you have good reasons.

Comment: @guigui42 if that is true then the French are not implementing the relevant part of the Schengen visa code.  This code calls for consulates to process visa applications for non-residents who have a good reason not to apply in their home country.

Comment: @Jonas if someone is living in a country, then that person is generally a resident of the country, not a non-resident.